# GPIO not working after installing the webiopi

Tags: raspbian, gpio, rpi.gpio, webiopi

I was doing programs with LED's and the GPIO after I installed the Webiopi to access it from the internet it didnt work anymore, I tried installing the latest version of Python and the rpg.gpio and updating the latest version of Pi and nothing, I'm measuring with my multimiter and I get no output. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try my test program to see if the gpios are still functional.

http://elinux.org/R-Pi_Troubleshooting#Testing

It's more likely that you have managed to get incompatible software versions in the process of installing webiopi.